# How to add a new class or controller into core?

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I'm trying to find out how to create a new class or controller, instead of overriding an existing one. So I've created controller test in `/controllers/front/TestController.php`

```
class TestFrontController extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'test';

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        echo "Test!";
    }  
}
```

But if I go to `mystore.com/index.php?controller=test` I get a white page. I have removed `class_index.php` in `cache` before this.

What else do I need for my new controller to work?

p.s. The debug line says that:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Test' not found in C:\LS\mystore\www\classes\controller\Controller.php on line 128
```

Well, it seems that each controller must have it's own class, but that may not be correct as I have also created a simple Test class. This class must also have a database table.

`[`**1. upd**`]` I did a test table and class must contain $definitions to it's fields, but still don't have a clue why I can't run the script:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Test::run() in C:\LS\mystore\www\classes\Dispatcher.php on line 348
```

That's what my debug error message saying now.

`[`**2. upd**`]` I can add a Run method to my Test class, but I think it makes no sense:

```
class TestCore extends ObjectModel
{   
    public $id_test;

    protected $_test;

        /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = array(
        'table' => 'test',
        'primary' => 'id_test',
        'fields' => array(
            'id_test' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isInt'),
        ),
    );

    public function Run()
    {
        echo "Test!";
    }
}
```

It will display only the `Test!`, not the content and other stuff, other classes do not have this method at all and are working fine.

**solution**. everything is ok, i also had a test.php file in my override/controllers/front, so it was the reason.

Comment: you can put your solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a file called "test.php" containing code presented below:

```
<?php
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
ControllerFactory::getController('TestFrontController')->run();
```

Comment: If it's in the root folder, so it's not helping.